# JPA identity generation strategies

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

1. What is the default name of sequence for `@GeneratedValue(strategy =
   GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` can I force all entities to use different
   sequences and provide custom name generator for that sequence.
2. Is it possible to provide programmatically method for
   `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` to switch between
   `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and
   `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` apart from
   custom orm.xml files

Background:I'm connecting my app to another application databases, there is not much that I can change on the database side.

This application can use SQL Server or PostgreSQL. In SQL Server mode `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` is used. My current codebase is using it. Now I have to provide support for postgresql, where sequence generated identities are used. I though about overriding it with orm.xml. All sequences are named (table_name)_seq so automatic name generation would save a lot of boilerplate xml.

Comment: AUTO is defined by the JPA provider. You dont control it. Selecting AUTO passes control to the provider.

Comment: orm.xml is your JPA friendly way to override specifics, but you can use EclipseLink customizers as shown here: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/dbws/creating_dbws_services002.htm for customizers.  I don't have a published example of setting a sequence on the descriptor, but the descriptor javadoc can help if you go that route, or you can add named ones to each class and register the platform specific sequence as shown here https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CustomSequencing#Registering_Sequence

Comment: Thank you Chris, that is something worth looking into.